Prove that $\mu(B\setminus A_\infty)=0$
Let $(X,\mathcal{E},\mu)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{E}$ a family closed with respect to countable unions and intersections that contains the empty set. From the properties of sup, we can find an increasing family $\{A_n\}\in\mathcal{A}$ such that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mu(A_n)=\sup\{\mu(A) | A\in\mathcal{A}\}$$
and set $A_\infty:=\bigcup_nA_n$. I want to prove that if $B\in\mathcal{A}$, then $\mu(B\setminus A_\infty)=0$.
Clearly we have that $\mu(A_\infty)=\mu(\bigcup_nA_n)=\lim_n\mu(A_n)=\sup\{\mu(A) | A\in\mathcal{A}\}$. I tried to use the equality
$$\mu(B\setminus A_\infty)=\mu(B)-\mu(B\cap A_\infty)$$
and prove that $\mu(B\cap A_\infty)=\mu(B)$, but I don't see how can I obtain this, since no hypothesis about set containment is involved (so we can have for example that $B$ and $A_\infty$ are disjoint).

Since $\mu(A_\infty\cup B)\ge\mu(A_\infty)$ and $A_\infty\cup B \in \mathcal{A}$, we must have $\mu(A_\infty\cup B)=\mu(A_\infty)$. Therefore,
$$0=\mu(A_\infty\cup B)-\mu(A_\infty)=\mu((A_\infty\cup B)\smallsetminus A_\infty)=\mu(B\smallsetminus A_\infty).$$

If $\mu(B\setminus A_\infty) > 0$, Then by countable additivity, $\mu(A_\infty\cup(B\setminus A_\infty)) = \mu(A_\infty) + \mu(B\setminus A_\infty) > \mu(A_\infty)$, which contradicts the fact that $A_n$ is a maximizing sequence in $\mathcal{A}$ for $\mu$.
